# Getting exit code 255 when trying to launch diffmerge from svn

Tags: svn, osx-snow-leopard, diffmerge

I'm trying to integrate DiffMerge with svn (version 1.6.16) on snow leopard, following the steps provided [here](http://semicrazy.wordpress.com/2009/10/08/using-diffmerge-as-your-subversion-external-merge-tool/). I made the following changes:

1) Created a script that looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIFFMERGE_PATH=/Applications/DiffMerge/DiffMerge.app
DIFFMERGE_EXEC=${DIFFMERGE_PATH}/Contents/MacOS/DiffMerge
${DIFFMERGE_EXEC} --nosplash -m -t1="Incoming"  -t2="Original" -t3="Current" -r="$4" "$2" "$1" "$3"
```

2) Ran `chmod +x ~/Scripts/diffmerge-svnmerge.sh`

3) Added the following command to ~/.subversion/config file:

```
merge-tool-cmd = <HOME>/Scripts/diffmerge-svnmerge.sh
```

4) For testing purposes, I made sure to get a conflict when trying to update a file, and used the 'l' option to launch DiffMerge to resolve the conflict. I get the following error message every time: `The external merge tool exited with exit code 255`

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of ${DIFFMERGE_EXEC} put "echo" and see what it outputs. You are interested in parameters that it gets.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me (Subversion 1.7.5)

```sh
#!/bin/bash
DIFFMERGE_PATH=/Applications/DiffMerge.app
DIFFMERGE_EXEC=${DIFFMERGE_PATH}/Contents/MacOS/DiffMerge
DIFFMERGE_ARGS=()
COLCOUNT=1
for I in "$@"; do
    case "${I}" in
        "-E")
            ;;
        "-L")
            DIFFMERGE_ARGS[${#DIFFMERGE_ARGS[*]}]="-t${COLCOUNT}"
            COLCOUNT=$((${COLCOUNT}+1))
            ;;
        *)
            DIFFMERGE_ARGS[${#DIFFMERGE_ARGS[*]}]="${I}"
            ;;
    esac
    echo "Arg: ${I}" >> /Users/kosh/tmp/diffmerge.cmd
done
${DIFFMERGE_EXEC} --nosplash "${DIFFMERGE_ARGS[@]}"
exit ${?}
```

Answer (score 0):

exit code 255 seems to happen when path is not found. For me it also happened when using ~/ (tilde) path to my external diff tool. I use IntelliJ's `idea merge`